# Array to string conversion error, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to save to database my data, but I get error "Array to string conversion". It's my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $listapacjentow = Patient::pluck('nazwisko','id');
    return view('leczenie.create')->with('listapacjentow', $listapacjentow);
}

public function store(CreateOperacjaRequest $request)
{
    $operacja = new Operacja($request->all());
    $PacjenciIds = $request->input('PacjentList');
    $operacja->user()->associate($PacjenciIds);
    $operacja->save();

    return redirect('leczenie');
}
```

It's my form

```
<div class="form-group">
<div  class="col-md-4 control-label">
    {!! Form::label('PacjentList','Wybierz pacjenta:') !!}
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    {!! Form::select('PacjentList[]', $listapacjentow); !!}
</div>
```

When I return $operacja is everything ok, but I can't save it to database

Comment: Try `dd($request->input('Pacjenlist'));` to see what it looks like

Comment: Its the same problem. Btw. When i add in console, everything its working

Comment: I mean use dd at the very top of the store method to output the result

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => "2"
]

Comment: Its return good user_id from form

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42455471/3789576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this approch in your `store` method.

```
$operacja = new Operacja($request->all());
$operacja->user_id = $request->input('PacjentList.0');
$operacja->save();
$operacja->user()->saveMany($patients);
```

Comment: Its relation one to many. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach(). Yesterday, i tried attach . Can you paste me code, after change, im new in laravel

Comment: Its doesnt get user_id  . Error is Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: operacjas.user_id.  In my system patient can has many operation. If i create i operation, i choose date, name, and surname of patient from select, but in table operacjas, i have user_id

Comment: Why storing user_id in an array if there can be only one?

Comment: I've updated my answer again according to what I understand from your project

Comment: Man, you are my next God. Im new in stackoverflow. How can I thanks to you ?

Comment: I deleted $operacja->user()->saveMany($patients), and its working

Comment: Upvote my answer mark it solved your question, that'll do ;)

Comment: If it's working, I've a few recommendations for you, first, you don't need to have an array to your select, so remove the square brackets `[]` and the `.0` in the store method. Second it's a really bad habits IMHO to use `$request->all();` with mass assignment. Consider using `only` instead and give it only the keys that you want to be stored.

Comment: So, basically, the only thing worked for OP is `.0` which is not a solution, but kind of hack. The real solution is what you did recommend next, removing [] which I've recommended 40 minutes before that.

Comment: Ok, i will remeber

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, don't be that guy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate only one user with `Operacja`, do this:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $listapacjentow); !!}

$operacja = Operacja::create($request->all());
```

If you want to add many users to the `Operacja`, you'll need to revert one to many relationship, so `User` will have `operacja_id` and `Operacja` will not have `user_id`.

If you want to make `Operacja` have many users and a user could have many `Operacja`, use many to many relationship.

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski please look at the error message and find out at what exactly line you're getting the error message now (controller, model, view...?). Please show me related code.

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 647: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into "operacjas" ("nazwauslugi", "datauslugi", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (qw, qw, 3, 2017-02-25 11:32:56, 2017-02-25 11:32:56))

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski it absolutely can't be the same problem with updated code. It seems you didn't remove the other code. Also, it's really possible you're using completely wrong relationship as I described in my answer.

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski doing that you're creating an array and then taking the first element from that array. This solution smells. Code from my answer does this right, PeterPan666 recommended you exactly the same in the latest comments. I'm writing this for the guys who'll meet the same problem in the future, so they know what to do.

Comment: @MateuszSołobodowski yes, and this is exactly the same code as in my answer. With redundant `$operacja->user_id =` and `save()` lines. Why using `save()` if you're already using mass assignment? Just use `create()` method. Also, you don't need to use `multiple` if you want to choose just one user.